# Origin of “sick to my stomach”

Tags: phrase-origin

Where does the phrase *sick to my stomach* come from? Never stopped to think of it before. It doesn’t even seem grammatically correct.

Comment: It's an [idiom](http://esl-bits.net/idioms/id542.htm), so it doesn't have to be grammatically or semantically "correct". All it has to do is have a meaning that speakers & listeners and writers & readers understand. There are many others, e.g., "I'm **[sick to death](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sick)** of your whining", "sick at heart", "sick as a parrot" (all three in Macmillan Dictionary).

Comment: I'm sick up to here with this sort of question. Are we being asked to explain the grammar? The meaning? Try to find the first recorded use? Not Constructive, I feel.

Comment: @Fumble: This is an etymology Q: "Where does the phrase ... come from?" OP apparently knows the meaning but indirectly questions its grammaticality. OP thinks, perhaps, it should be "sick **in** my stomach" or "my stomach feels bad" or some such, but that's semantics and not grammar. Anglophones are famous for grammar & sex fetishes & fixations. We have a Lowthy heritage.

Comment: @Bill Franke: I don't really understand the point you're making, but I've posted an answer which hopefully will simultaneously explain to OP how we got where we are, ***and*** why it's Not Constructive. Essentially, commonplace idioms don't necessarily conform to current concepts of grammar or "best" choice of preposition - which I assume is what you meant by your first comment.

Comment: @Fumble: [I found this gem](http://books.google.com.tw/books?id=DMtNcKtBkcQC&pg=PA145&dq=%22sick+in+my+stomach%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=B-KuUKaKOaLPmAWI34H4Ag&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22sick%20in%20my%20stomach%22&f=false): "Speakers in the north tend to say 'sick to my stomach'; 'sick in my stomach' is used in the midland; and 'sick at my stomach' is used in the midland and south (Shuy 29).... Some of these forms may be unfamiliar and even seem wrong, but they are all considered standard, ...." My point was that the OP asked for only one answer: the source of the expression.

Comment: @Bill Franke: I'd have thought many if not most regional variations only exist for a limited period of time, being caused by the fact that linguistic change *takes time*, and spreads unevenly from region to region. I'm sure much will change in this new age of instant global communications (and in particular, the Internet). But on your/OP's "point", the answer is that the underlying "source" of *sick to one's stomach = fed up* is trivial metaphoric extension. And the current preferred choice of preposition is effectively "random".

Comment: @Fumble: I didn't bother to check the source of the expression: not interesting to me. All I commented on was its grammaticality. I don't know enough about the stability of regional variations, but you're probably correct about how homogenized future generations will become because of current communications technology. When milk was sold in glass bottles & only pasteurized, the cream floated to the top & could be whipped or churned. Homogenization is bland, boring, & obesifying. But better than powdered milk.

Comment: I agree w/ the initial remark (and reaction) from @FumbleFingers – nothing wrong with the question per se, but the lack of details is rather annoying. As came out in the ensuing conversation, what's the real issue? Its origin? Its preposition? Its medical accuracy? Its roots? The timeframe it entered the vernacular? Surely an O.P. could elaborate with a little more than "I've never stopped to think of it before." If that's the case, I'd prefer an O.P. think about it first, do some research, and if a mystery still remains, they could  then ask a more _informed_ question, sharing their findings.

Comment: Question should be taken offline but not because "Not Constructive". OP should show evidence of research so that people who choose to try to answer the question have a starting point. Voting to close question for now NARQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google n-gram shows it [showing up around 1890 for the first time](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sick%20to%20my%20stomach,%20stomachache&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).  Here's [an editorial from 1905](http://books.google.com/books?id=zgRAAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22sick%20to%20my%20stomach%22&pg=PA241#v=onepage&q=%22sick%20to%20my%20stomach%22&f=false) where a reader asks the same exact question you have.  The editor's explanation is that the speaker means it for emphasis or inclusiveness: i.e., not just sick at their stomach, but from somewhere (head, mouth, somewhere else) through and including their stomach.

Answer (score 1):

I voted to close as Not Constructive (as Bill Franke says, it's an *idiom*, so concepts of present-day "grammaticality" don't really come into it). But I disagree with the only existing answer, so...

[image]

I stopped the chart at 1970, but if you just look at [the last 60 years](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sick%20to%20my%20stomach,sick%20at%20my%20stomach&year_start=1945&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) (when most of us were learning English), it's pretty obvious the switch to *"to"* rather than *"at"* has been almost unanimous. Even the relatively tiny number of instances in modern times probably includes a significant proportion that are just citations of earlier usages.

---

I'd also note that OP may be thinking primarily (or *only*) of the now-ubiquitous *(I'm exasperated)* sense. That's a trivial metaphoric extension which could have applied *at any time* in the past - it's just that we use it *a lot more nowadays*...

[image]

The particular choice of preposition isn't governed by any considerations of grammar. Possibly the current preference for *"to"* is influenced by analogy to related expressions like [I've had it up to here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had%20it%20up%20to%20here&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) (which as that NGram shows, also really took off after the war).

There really is nothing unusual about such shifts in idiomatic usage, nor is there anything unusual about the fact that natural "lag" sometimes means the version we actually use doesn't fit perfectly with our more general concepts of "grammaticality" at any given time.

Comment: Remember that it America, saying one is sick normally means nothing more than that one is ill, not that one is about to *be* sick.

Comment: @tchrist: I didn't know that. Well, to be honest I've never really thought about it that way - if you're *sick **of** someone/something*, you're fed up with it. If you're just *sick* (or *sick **with** something*), you're ill. Totally separate words, to me. But NGrams prevalence figures for [sick of him](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sick+of+him&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=) are much the same in US/UK corpuses, and I'd have thought they'd practically all be for the "fed up" sense.

Answer (score -1):

As I studied to be, and worked as, a firefighter/paramedic, I often spoke with many doctors and other professional medical colleagues, many were friends. I always loathed "sick to my stomach", preferring good ol' "nauseous" personally. I inquired of nearly all of them, situation permitting, over the years, where they'd learned the idiom originated. My informal poll of many medically-trained persons produced -no- clear result. I'd venture to say that there's almost as many learned opinions as there are people who care enough to ask the question. Can we simply say it's ancient, as are many distressed tummies?

Comment: I think you were barking up the wrong tree. You wouldn’t ask a dr where a linguistic construct originated any more than you’d ask your English prof where stomach aches come from.